# What could cause this DXA error? Error in semantic schema configuration: Found field semantics which uses the prefix 's', but there is no

Tags: dxa

I have this error in TRI when trying to load a page. It looks like the website does not have all the configuration for the scemantics mapping, but I did publish all the pages, and reloaded the web application. I even validated that I have a couple of binary variants by browsing the broker.

What could cause this error? And which resources do I need to have in the broker storage for the scemantic mapping?

Btw, I am using a sneak preview version of TRI-JAVA, but I have the feeling that I would have the same issue in the public .NET version of TRI.

**Error message**

`Error in semantic schema configuration: Found field semantics which uses the prefix 's', but there is no vocabulary with this prefix.`

**Detail**

```
Caused by: com.sdl.webapp.common.api.localization.LocalizationFactoryException: Error in semantic schema configuration: Found field semantics which uses the prefix 's', but there is no vocabulary with this prefix. 
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.semantics.SemanticsConverter.createSemanticFields(SemanticsConverter.java:112) ~[webapp-common-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT] 
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.semantics.SemanticsConverter.createSemanticFields(SemanticsConverter.java:105) ~[webapp-common-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT] 
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.semantics.SemanticsConverter.convertSemantics(SemanticsConverter.java:49) ~[webapp-common-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT] 
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.createLocalization(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[webapp-common-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT] 
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.TridionLocalizationResolver.createLocalization(TridionLocalizationResolver.java:71) ~[webapp-tridion-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

Comment: Did you check my answer to this question http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11342/tri-adding-new-vocabularies

Comment: @BartKoopman Thanks, I did not see that excellent guide yet.

Comment: I'd say it's better to refer to TRI (which is real and exists) than DXA (which is either vapourware or the same thing as TRI, but with added mumbo-jumbo). Maybe later, if DXA becomes a recognised term for what you're talking about, you could change back to that.

Comment: What's with you and being so attached to names @DominicCronin? :)

Comment: It's not all names. Last I checked, Dom prefers #tridion over #SDLTridion but is okay with SDL Web. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vocabularies are set in global app data, and should have been set when doing the Content Porter import. So I guess you might have missed to register the TRI specific app data for Content Porter. This you do by adding a XML file (for example calling it `Tridion Reference Implementation.xml`) in `%TRIDION_HOME%\config\ImportExport\ApplicationData` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApplicationDataCategories xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/ImportExport/Configuration/2013">
    <ApplicationDataCategory name="TRI" description="Tridion Reference Implementation">
        <ApplicationId pattern="http://www.sdl.com/tridion/SemanticMapping/vocabularies" tcmUriXPath="" />
        <ApplicationId pattern="http://www.sdl.com/tridion/SemanticMapping/typeof" tcmUriXPath="//@xlink:href" />
    </ApplicationDataCategory>
</ApplicationDataCategories>
```

This should normally be done by the TRI installer.

To correct your app data you can use Bart's custom page for that: **[Custom Page](https://code.google.com/p/sdl-tridion-world/source/browse/AppData%20Custom%20Page/trunk/)**

Comment: Good thinking, the Tridion Reference Implementation.xml is mentioned in the manual in step 3 of http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Reference%20Implementation-v1/GUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA. I wonder why the TRI installer `import.ps1` does not do this for you.

Comment: @JanH do you really wonder why `import.ps1` does not do it, or would you like it to do it for you?

Comment: @BartKoopman: both :) I wonder why and I would like the installer to perform this important task. I figured out the why part: The installer is using the Core Service and the installer can be run from any machine while the Tridion CM and Core Service are on a remote machine. Of course the installer cannot deploy a file into the CM's file system. Hence you need to copy this manually.

Comment: Thanks Niclas and Bart. This solved the issue! From the DXA webapp logs it was not so obvious. I checked Bart's answer on http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/11343/88 and took option 1: rerun the import script. I also re-imported the GoogleAnalytics module.

Comment: I'm trying to keep trex clean. If you guys want to announce a new product, or rename stuff, go ahead, but this isn't the place for it. Here, consistent naming is valued. See you on meta... :-)